Can probabilistic predictions be obtained from gradient boosting models CatBoost and XGBoost?
I'm looking for probabilistic predictions ($\Pr(Y\mid X=x)$) using CatBoost or XGBoost for a continuous target variable that is in [0, 1] (i.e., ratio). Can I use the official library to generate probabilistic predictions rather than $E[Y\mid X=x]$?

Do you mean an estimate of the full conditional density (to which Björn is alluding) or a prediction that isn't zero or one?

Thanks, Dave. I'm looking for P(Y|X=x) in [0, 1] and not E[Y|X=x].

So the full conditional distribution?

Yes. The full conditional dist.

Yes, you could just do multiple separate quantile regression models (say, for 50th, 2.5th and 97.5th quantile). That gives you a point estimate and prediction intervals. Admittedly, you cannot fully ensure that the ordering of the outputs of the multiple models are logically ordered, with enough data and enough trees in the model (at a low enough learning rate) this ought to be the case. In contrast, you can set-up neural networks with 3 outputs from the same NN in a way that 100% ensures this.
In general, there's conformal prediction, which would even be applicable when predicting the probability for a binary (or categorical) target. There you'd need to have enough data to hold out enough of it to then figure out the correct prediction uncertainty around your predictions.

In contrast, you can set-up neural networks with 3 outputs from the same NN in a way that 100% ensures this. I thought quantile crossover was still an open problem for neural networks.

Just define strictly increasing outputs. Let's say we have 3 outputs, let's call them $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$. We leave take one as it is, e.g. the one that aims to predict the median, let's say that's $p_2$. Then you set $p_1' = p_2 - e^{p_1}$ and $p_3' = p_2 + e^{p_3}$. That ensures the outputs are ordered, now you just apply some suitable loss function to these outputs (e.g. pinball loss). Done. Ideas like that were used in various Kaggle competitions like e.g. the "OSIC Pulmonary Fibrosis Progression" one.

Thanks, @Björn. A quick follow-up. Some of the predictions are outside the [0, 1] interval. Is there any way I can ensure model predictions are bounded $\in [0,1]$. Your answer helped me. Thanks.

Some models ensure predictions are between $[0, 1]$ automatically (e.g. beta-regression, logistic regression [yes, some LR software lets you provide values other than 0 and 1], random forest if all training data is in $[0, 1]$ because trees are averaged, but e.g. not XGBoost because trees are added up). if your model does not already ensure this is to use a logit (or any other transformation that projects $(-\infty, \infty)$ to $[0, 1]$) on the model output. In some model it's not directly possible to do that, in which case you'd have to modify the loss-function so that it builds that in.
